# How to produce a projected graph from a MultiGraph Bipartite network

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have some multigraph bipartite networks where some nodes have several edges, all of the edges are directed. An example of one of my graphs:

[image]

I want to create projected graphs for both V1 vertices (i.e. x nodes) and connect them if they share the same neighbour from V2 vertices (i.e. r nodes). And vice versa.

But when trying to use Networkx and its projected_graph methods, they are all "not defined for multigraphs" despite allowing multigraphs to be returned? It has no explanation as to why.

I'm very new to graph and network theory, but I would assume that just because a node is allowed more than one edge wouldn't make it impossible to make a projected graph from it? If I am wrong, is there another way I can create projection graphs like I describe above?